# How to Install Justinmind Prototyper in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, software-installation, wine, tools

I want to install Justinmind Prototyper to my Ubuntu 12.04

How can i Install Justinmind Prototyper tool in my Ubuntu 12.04 PC

http://www.justinmind.com/

Is there any way to install this tool in ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

[JustinMind](http://www.justinmind.com/download) does not seems available for Linux. You won't be able to install it.

You can still try to launch using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) or with a Windows Virtual machine.

Edit : [It seems possible with Wine](https://twitter.com/richardhare/status/397436789712891904).

Comment: is it work properly using wine.